# OAuthWebSecurity Migrating from OpenID 2.0 to OpenID Connect

Tags: facebook, asp.net-mvc-4, oauth, google-api, webmatrix-3

Google had earlier announced the deprecation and discontinuation of openID 2.0 on April 2015. Unfortunately for most people like me, our existing applications already have a bunch of codes written based on this service using **OAuthWebSecurity** from **DotNetOpenAuth nuget package.**

Is there an update to this change on this nuget package that will assist to migrate to this new update rather than abandoning all my past efforts by searching for alternatives such as OWIN as explained in http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on

Secondly, is there a possibility that other platforms such as **Facebook, Twitter, LinkedIn** will also abandon OpenID 2.0 as well?

```
OAuthWebSecurity.RequestAuthentication("google", Href("~/Account/RegisterService", new { returnUrl }));
```

Answer (score 1):

For news about DotNetOpenAuth you will have to ask the maintainers of the project. They are the only ones with insight into future development.

Facebook, Twitter, and LinkedIn don't use OpenID. Twitter uses OAuth 1.0 while Facebook and LinkedIn use OAuth 2. As of the writing of this answer, none of them have announced plans to move away from their current authentication standards.